# WPF - Button context menu not displayed properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

For some time I'm working on a WPF application. Some weeks ago I've had added a context menu to a button. Back the it was displayed properly.

Then I worked on other areas of the application without changing or even using that context menu.

Now I realize that the context menu isn't displayed properly. As you can see on the attached picture there is a blue bordered area to the left that I'm sure wasn't there some weeks ago.
[image]
I've looked the code deeply, but can't figure out why the menu is displayed wrong.

Here's the XAML of the button with attached context menu:

```
<!-- NOTE: 1) This Button only contains a context menu and is not
              bound to a command itself. 
           2) An EventTrigger is set up to also open the context 
              menu on left click.
           3) As a ContextMenu isn't part of the VisualTree and 
              thus the menu items can't be out-of-the-box bound
              to commands a BindingProxy (custom class) is used -->
<Button Content="_Manage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsMenuAllowed}">
  <Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
      <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
              <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Button.Triggers>
  <Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="_New" 
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, 
                          Path=Data.CmdNew}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="_Rename" 
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, 
                          Path=Data.CmdRename}"/>
      <MenuItem Header="_Duplicate" 
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, 
                          Path=Data.CmdDuplicate}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="Delete"  
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, 
                          Path=Data.CmdDelete}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Many styles are set up the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
<!-- Define the default style for GroupBox -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
  <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Height="20" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Define the global style for PasswordBoxes -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,3"/>
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>

<!-- Define the global style for TextBoxes -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,3" />
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
      <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
              Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for the Separator -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,6,0,6"/>
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for StackPanel -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,6,3,3"/>
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for Button -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="70"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,3"/>
</Style>

<!--Define a style for disabled Image Button -->
<Style x:Key="ImageEnabled" TargetType="Image">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for ComboBoxes -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,3"/>
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for Label -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,3,0" />
</Style>


<!-- Define the default style for CheckBox -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,6,3,3" />
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for Rectangles (Canvas drawing) -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
  <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#6080bc"/>
  <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for Lines (Canvas drawing) -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Line}">
  <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#6080bc"/>
  <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
</Style>

<!-- Define the default style for Path (Canvas drawing) -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
  <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#6080bc"/>
  <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
</Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for the issue?

Comment: Did you already try bisecting through your VCS to pinpoint when the blue box appeared? My guess would be that some of the styling is responsible for that. And this space looks like the placeholder for checkable (context) menu items.

Comment: Try to put `Style="{x:Null}"` to the `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem`. Does it help?

Comment: @Rekshino I tried setting Style="{x:Null}" to ContextMenu, all MenuItems and also to the two Separators. Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: But I've found it: it was one of the last three styles applied in App.xaml. I moved the style definitions for Rectangle, Line and Path to the user control where they are needed. And now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your code and am able to reproduce the blue bordered area on the context menu.

By commenting out the style that targets a rectangle type the blue bordered area is removed. If you use this style elsewhere in your program you can try using an x:Key value to target the specific rectangles you require the border on.

The x:Type property affects all rectangles and my guess is that somewhere in the logical xaml tree the context menu contains a rectangle.